# php Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\paribibi/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR')

Tags: php, laravel, indexing

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\paribibi/public/index.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\paribibi\server.php on line 21

server.php line 21 - ""require_once **DIR**.'/public/index.php';""

what should i do now??

Comment: Is `public/index.php` really present at that path?

Comment: server.php and index.php are in root

Comment: So if `server.php` and `index.php` are in the same folder, why are you trying to include `index.php` from a subfolder?

Answer (score 1):

it means you public folder is missing index.php

just create a index.php file inside public directory

and paste this code-

```
 <?php

use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Check If Application Is Under Maintenance
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If the application is maintenance / demo mode via the "down" command we
| will require this file so that any prerendered template can be shown
| instead of starting the framework, which could cause an exception.
|
*/

if (file_exists(__DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php')) {
    require __DIR__.'/../storage/framework/maintenance.php';
}

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| this application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so we don't need to manually load our classes.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request using
| the application's HTTP kernel. Then, we will send the response back
| to this client's browser, allowing them to enjoy our application.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

$kernel = $app->make(Kernel::class);

$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```